# How to put list object to JSon object

Tags: java, json, servlets, arraylist, resultset

In servlet I am trying to put a list in json object, but i cant able to find what is the error. I am calling servlet from ajax call, Here is servlet code,

```
Latlng latlng=new Latlng();
List<Latlng> vehicleList = new ArrayList<Latlng>();

sql ="SELECT a.vehicleno,a.lat,a.lng,a.status,a.rdate,a.rtime from latlng a,vehicle_details b where a.vehicleno=b.vehicleno and b.clientid="+clientid +"  and b.groupid in(select groupid from group_details where groupname='"+gname+"' and clientid='"+clientid+"')";
              resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
              while(resultSet.next()){
                  String s=resultSet.getString("vehicleno");
                  latlng.setVehicleno(resultSet.getString("vehicleno"));
                  latlng.setLat(resultSet.getString("lat"));
                  latlng.setLat(resultSet.getString("lng"));
                  latlng.setLat(resultSet.getString("status"));
                  latlng.setLat(resultSet.getString("rdate"));
                  latlng.setLat(resultSet.getString("rtime"));
                  vehicleList.add(latlng);
                  System.out.println(vehicleList);
                  String json = new Gson().toJson(vehicleList);
                  response.setContentType("application/json"); 
                  response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
                  response.getWriter().write(json);
              }
     } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

is there anything wrong in it. It is not even displaying exception also.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in this code and stepping through it to see what happens? Currently it will never display an exception because you're basically swallowing any `ClassNotFoundException`s or `SQLException`s that occur (writing the exceptions to the console which isn't any help for servlet code). Also, you should probably put the last four lines in your `while-loop` just *after* it instead.

Comment: I tried with break points it execute the stmt and will not go into the while loop just comes to catch but not displaying execption

Comment: The exception will get printed to your IDE's console/output window. Try looking there, or put a breakpoint right on `e.printStackTrace()` and then inspect the `e` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this.

```
   while (resultSet.next()) {
        latlng=new Latlng();
        String s = resultSet.getString("vehicleno");
        latlng.setVehicleno(resultSet.getString("vehicleno"));
        latlng.setLat(resultSet.getString("lat"));
        latlng.setLat(resultSet.getString("lng"));
        latlng.setLat(resultSet.getString("status"));
        latlng.setLat(resultSet.getString("rdate"));
        latlng.setLat(resultSet.getString("rtime"));
        vehicleList.add(latlng);
    }
    System.out.println(vehicleList);
    String json = new Gson().toJson(vehicleList);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);
```